# 'Answer' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I have a model called `Answer` which has a `ForeignKey` relationship to another model called `Question`.  This means there can be several answers to question, naturally.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=_SURVEY_QUESTION_KINDS)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='answerers')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choices = models.ManyToManyField(Choice, null=True, blank=True) # <-- !
    text = models.CharField(max_length=_SURVEY_CHARFIELD_SIZE, blank=True)
```

Now I'm trying to create an `Answer` instance, and then set the M2M relationship to `Choice`, but I get the following error before even touching the M2M: `'Answer' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used.`

```
 ans = Answer(user=self._request.user,
              question=self._question[k],
              text=v)
 ans.save() # [1]
```

When I comment out `[1]` the problem goes away of course, but I don't understand why it comes up in the first place, because as you can see, I'm doing *nothing with the M2M at all!*

---

EDIT: It doesn't seem to be a problem with the name `choices` either.  I tried changing every occurence of it to `options` with the same problem.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't producing any errors for me (and you're right that it shouldn't). What does your Choice model look like? Any custom inits, meta classes, or inheritance? Any global/local variables in the module where you're either defining the models, or where you're instantiating Answer, that could collide with choices or options (though I note from you edit that you probably already thought of that).

Comment: Or custom save() method, perhaps, in your Answer model?

Comment: That's actually good news for me, that it's working for someone else.  I'll keep investigating.

Comment: (No, I don't have a custom save() method.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who took their time on this question.  The classes provided in my question weren't complete, because I thought the inner `Meta` classes didn't matter.  In fact, `Answer` looked like this:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    """
    We have two fields here to represent answers to different kinds of
    questions.  Since the text answers don't have any foreign key to anything
    relating to the question that was answered, we must have a FK to the
    question.
    """

    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = 'options'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s on "%s"' % (self.user, self.question)

    user     = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='answers')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    options  = models.ManyToManyField(Option, blank=True)
    text     = models.CharField(max_length=_SURVEY_CHARFIELD_SIZE, blank=True)
    answered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Take a look at `order_with_respect_to` and you'll understand where the error came from. :)